# mongoose Chaining with then and catch

Tags: javascript, mongoose

How To Convert This Function to Chaining with then and catch?
Is better to Chained?
I mean `User.findOne().then().catch()`

```
User.findOne({_id: msg.chat.id}, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    if (doc) {
      console.log(doc.name);
    } else {
      console.log('Empty');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you pass to `then` is called with the returned document (or null) if the operation succeeds, and the `catch` is called with the error if the operation fails (e.g. no connection).  Putting it together looks like this:

```
User.findOne({_id: msg.chat.id})
    .then(doc => {
        if (doc) {
            console.log(doc.name);
        } else {
            console.log('Empty');
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } 
    });
```

As an aside, when you are searching for one document by id, then you can use `findById`:

```
User.findById(msg.chat.id)
    .then(doc => {
        if (doc) {
            console.log(doc.name);
        } else {
            console.log('Empty');
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Hi @alex-young Can you Help me in This Question Please? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480868/cannot-read-property-of-null-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 1):

Better switch to `ES2017 async/await` syntax, you can avoid **Promise Hell**

```
async function foo () {
    try {
        var doc = await User.findOne({_id: msg.chat.id}).exec()         
        if (doc)
            return console.log(doc.name);
        console.log('Empty');    
    } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
}

foo()
```

This will help you when you're going to nest `DB` calls or using `for...loops`.

```
async function foo () {
    try {
        var users = await User.find({}).exec()

        for (var user in users) {
            var tweets = await Tweet.find({_user: user._id}).exec()
            user.tweets = tweets.map(t => t.text)
            await user.save() 
        }

    } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
}

foo()
```

Comment: What is hellish about Promises? Async/await is great and I use it frequently, but it is essentially just syntactic sugar around promises.  As an example of where promises are useful, your second piece of code is going to run `Tweet.find` sequentially for each user.  If you used `Promise.all` then you could run these queries in parallel.

Comment: Promises are good, but if you wanna make for example 5 nested async linear operations (**the result is used in the next one**), you'll end in some **callback hell** with promises and something that will take 5 lines of code, with promises will take over 20 with all the `.then(/*...*/)` and `.catch(/*...*/)`

Comment: Ans yes, `Promise.all` is the best when you want the execution in parallel

Comment: Hi @fernando-carvajal Can you Help me in This Question Please? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480868/cannot-read-property-of-null-in-mongoose)